# Copy array from product to quote item and order item

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, quote, array

I am copying single valued attributes from product to quote item and converting to order item. 
But is it possible to do that with an array? If yes - what's the process and what type should the table in the database be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such an attribute type as array in Magento. I suggest just serialising your array and then saving it to quote/order. You can alternatively use JSON format.